# React libray created with rollup not working css with srr or nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rollup, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

I create a simple react packages for personal uses (private package). But when I want to use it into nextjs project it's css not working with ssr. Actually, working but not ssr friendly. Here after component loading then css will be loaded. But I want it with ssr. I mean css also work with ssr.

`rollup.config.mjs-`

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: "dist/cjs/index.js",
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: "dist/esm/index.js",
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
            postcss()
        ],
        external: ["react", "react-dom"]
    },
    {
        input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
        plugins: [dts()],
        external: [/\.css$/]
    }
];
```